# SSRS - Export to pdf & background color

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 to build and edit SSRS reports.

When giving a certain background color to the report, and then exporting to PDF, I'm getting a pdf documents with the background color **only in the middle**, and **the margins of the page are white**.

Is there a way to export to pdf so that the background color will be a background to the entire page (and no white margins)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the report margins set to 1cm on all sides. setting it to 0 did the trick

Comment: I definitely agree to this. The same reason I always change the margin to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your report and body background colors are not set correctly.

You might only be setting the background color of your tablix or rectangle.

Go to Report and body properties to set the Background color you want.

[image: Report]

[image: Body Properties]

Comment: thanks, but actually I was setting it correctly. Problem was with the margins: I had the margins set to 1cm on all sides and once I set it to 0, the issue was solved